Is it possible to record a Mac's XDR screen in wide gamut?
I have a M1 MacBook Pro. It has a built-in XDR display.
I would like to capture video footage of games played on that display, in a wide gamut color space (preferably the one that comes with the display), so I can make a video out of it in Rec.2020 in FCP.
All fine, but macOS's built-in screen recorder captures in Rec.709 instead.
What are my options?
